# Accessing state in React render method after API request

Tags: json, reactjs, components, rendering

I'm working on my first complicated React app and I am making a request to a movie API. My site allows the user to do a search in a searchbar for whatever movie, show, actor, etc... that they are searching for. I'm pulling the user's search query and inserting it into an api request like this:

```
export const getDetails = (id) => {

return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/` + id +`?api_key=&language=en-US`)
 .then(function(response) {
   resolve(response)
 })
 .catch(function(error) {
   reject(error)
 })
})


}
```

I'm able to get the data like this and console.log it:

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
   import Header from '../header';
   import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
   import axios from 'axios';
   import Footer from '../Footer.js';
   import Searchbar from '../header/searchbar.js';
   import List from '../results/list';
   import {getDetails} from '../api/getDetails';


class Detail extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
            id: this.props.match.params.id,
            result: null,
            error: false,
    }
  }

    componentWillMount() {
        getDetails(this.state.id).then(function(response){
            this.setState({result: response});
            console.log(response.data.original_title);
            console.log(response.data.homepage);
            console.log(response.data.popularity);
            console.log(response.data.release_data);
            console.log(response.data.overview);
        }.bind(this)).catch(function(err) {
            this.setState({
                result:"There was a problem loading the results. Please try again.",
                error: true
            })
        }.bind(this))
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Header/>

                <div className="details-container">

                <h2>Details: </h2>


             </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Detail
```

Console.logging it in the componentWillMount function successfully logs the data but I am not able to access the data in the render function via something like {response.data.orginal_title). How would I render the data being logged in componentWillMount?

Comment: Two things. 1. `axios.get` returns a promise, so you don't need to wrap it in another promise. 2. You're not using the correct `this` in `this.setState`.

Comment: To add on to Eric's comment: in the render method you need to refer to {this.state.result.data.original_title} since you are setting the data to the component state key of 'result'

Comment: I'm a little confused about using the correct "this". I'm accidentally using the this of componentWillMount instead of the this from the Detail component? How woud I correct it?

Comment: I suggest you read up on `setState` and component state in React. You're calling `setState` but it seems like you don't know why. See https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; **You can access your state variables from within your render function via `this.state`.** Something like: `console.log(this.state.result.data.origin_title)` outside of the jsx and `{this.state.response.data.orginal_title}` inside the jsx.

P.S. You are using the correct `this`.

The following are picky recommendations and explanations, feel free to disregard.

1. It's recommended to make requests for data in `componentDidMount`. That can be read here in the docs for [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).
2. You're using arrow functions already in your get details function, if you convert the rest of your functions to arrow functions you no longer have to explicitly bind `this` to each one; it's automatically set be the this of it's parent. See the "No Separate This" section in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
3. If you don't need any of the header information I would save `response.data` into your state so you don't have to type as much when you want to access the data. `this.state.result.original_title` vs `this.state.result.data.original_title`. That's just me and I'm lazy.
4. axios does return a promise like Eric said so you don't actually need to wrap it in the extra promise. You can just straight up return it and since arrow functions automatically return one line expressions you can spiff that up into a one liner:

   ```
   export const getDetails = id => axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}?api_key=&language=en-US`)
   ```
5. Finally you should be able to access the data you've stored in your state from your render function as mentioned in #3 above. Outside of the JSX you can console.log it like normal `console.log(this.state.result)`, inside your JSX, however, you will need to make sure you escape with `{}` like: `<div>{this.result.original_title}</div>`

Small working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/zqz6vpmrw3

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
{this.state.result}
```

inside the render.